# How can I store data from custom fields to custom tables?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, database

I know how to make custom fields for my custom post types. I also know there is the `Advanced Custom Fields`plugin.

But I need to know how I can store my custom fields in my custom post type to my custom DB tables. I've been looking for tutorials, but I only find [how to create SQL tables in plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).

How can I fetch "my data" (and save it in my own tables) and at the same time save the other data for the page the normal way?

Comment: When you cay "fecth my data", you refer to the data in your custom table of the data in the custom field?

Comment: I mean the data that is entered into custom fields and submitted when I click the "save new post" button. I just want to store the data in my custom fields into my custom tables.

Answer (score 1):

Steven, I think you are looking for the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action, you should create the function you want to use and use the `add_action` function.

You can find the data from the custom fields in the `$_POST` array.

You don't have to worry about the "other content", at least if with that you are referring to the title, content, categories.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great post by Austin Ginder: https://anchor.host/acf-custom-fields-stored-in-custom-table/.

I've also come up with a free plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-fields-in-custom-table/